# Missing resize event for child widgets in custom layout manager

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

In PyQt5, I'm trying to use a ([FlowLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html)) with scaling label images in it. The scaling images themselves work like expected when testing with a normal BoxLayout and implement the method `resizeEvent(self, evt)` where the scaling is done.

However, when I try to use it with a custom FlowLayout, the label images do no longer receive a resize event when resizing the outer container (the listener is only executed once at the widget creation), thus the images do not scale. The Problem can be seen here:

[image]

After shrinking, images are cut:

[image]

Why do the images no longer receive the resizeEvent?

Code for the layout manager is from [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/109408/is-there-a-qt-layout-grid-that-can-dynamically-change-row-and-column-counts-to-best-fit-the-space/6):

```
# Code from Qt Docs and modified/adapted by jonB

class FlowLayout(QLayout):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget=None, margin: int=-1, hSpacing: int=-1, vSpacing: int=-1):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.itemList = list()
        self.m_hSpace = hSpacing
        self.m_vSpace = vSpacing

        self.setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)

    def __del__(self):
        # copied for consistency, not sure this is needed or ever called
        item = self.takeAt(0)
        while item:
            item = self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item: QLayoutItem):
        self.itemList.append(item)

    def horizontalSpacing(self) -> int:
        if self.m_hSpace >= 0:
            return self.m_hSpace
        else:
            return self.smartSpacing(QStyle.PM_LayoutHorizontalSpacing)

    def verticalSpacing(self) -> int:
        if self.m_vSpace >= 0:
            return self.m_vSpace
        else:
            return self.smartSpacing(QStyle.PM_LayoutVerticalSpacing)

    def count(self) -> int:
        return len(self.itemList)

    def itemAt(self, index: int) -> typing.Union[QLayoutItem, None]:
        if 0 <= index < len(self.itemList):
            return self.itemList[index]
        else:
            return None

    def takeAt(self, index: int) -> typing.Union[QLayoutItem, None]:
        if 0 <= index < len(self.itemList):
            return self.itemList.pop(index)
        else:
            return None

    def expandingDirections(self) -> Qt.Orientations:
        return Qt.Orientations(Qt.Orientation(0))

    def hasHeightForWidth(self) -> bool:
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width: int) -> int:
        height = self.doLayout(QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
        return height

    def setGeometry(self, rect: QRect) -> None:
        super().setGeometry(rect)
        self.doLayout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self) -> QSize:
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self) -> QSize:
        size = QSize()
        for item in self.itemList:
            size = size.expandedTo(item.minimumSize())

        margins = self.contentsMargins()
        size += QSize(margins.left() + margins.right(), margins.top() + margins.bottom())
        return size

    def smartSpacing(self, pm: QStyle.PixelMetric) -> int:
        parent = self.parent()
        if not parent:
            return -1
        elif parent.isWidgetType():
            return parent.style().pixelMetric(pm, None, parent)
        else:
            return parent.spacing()

    def doLayout(self, rect: QRect, testOnly: bool) -> int:
        left, top, right, bottom = self.getContentsMargins()
        effectiveRect = rect.adjusted(+left, +top, -right, -bottom)
        x = effectiveRect.x()
        y = effectiveRect.y()
        lineHeight = 0

        for item in self.itemList:
            wid = item.widget()
            spaceX = self.horizontalSpacing()
            if spaceX == -1:
                spaceX = wid.style().layoutSpacing(QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Horizontal)
            spaceY = self.verticalSpacing()
            if spaceY == -1:
                spaceY = wid.style().layoutSpacing(QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Vertical)

            nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + spaceX
            if nextX - spaceX > effectiveRect.right() and lineHeight > 0:
                x = effectiveRect.x()
                y = y + lineHeight + spaceY
                nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + spaceX
                lineHeight = 0

            if not testOnly:
                item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

            x = nextX
            lineHeight = max(lineHeight, item.sizeHint().height())

        return y + lineHeight - rect.y() + bottom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resizeEvent` is only called on your labels when they are resized. The layout manger `FlowLayout` did never resize its children. See the following line in `doLayout`

```
item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))
```

Here the new size of the child is set to `item.sizeHint()` which is `item`'s current size by default (can be changed by overwriting `sizeHint` in your widget class for labels).

The following updated `doLayout` uses `sizeHint()` if the container is wide enough to display at least one item. Otherwise, the items are resized (aspect ratio is kept) such that their width can be fully displayed in one column. This code is just for illustration. You still have to do finer adjustments to incorporate spacing and borders into the resize computations. Changes are marked with `######…`.

```
def doLayout(self, rect: QRect, testOnly: bool) -> int:
    left, top, right, bottom = self.getContentsMargins()
    effectiveRect = rect.adjusted(+left, +top, -right, -bottom)
    x = effectiveRect.x()
    y = effectiveRect.y()
    lineHeight = 0

    for item in self.itemList:
        ###########################
        itemSize = item.sizeHint()
        itemNewWidth = min(rect.width(), itemSize.width())
        itemSize = QtCore.QSize(itemNewWidth, itemSize.height() * itemNewWidth / itemSize.width())

        wid = item.widget()
        spaceX = self.horizontalSpacing()
        if spaceX == -1:
            spaceX = wid.style().layoutSpacing(QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Horizontal)
        spaceY = self.verticalSpacing()
        if spaceY == -1:
            spaceY = wid.style().layoutSpacing(QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Vertical)

        nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + spaceX
        if nextX - spaceX > effectiveRect.right() and lineHeight > 0:
            x = effectiveRect.x()
            y = y + lineHeight + spaceY
            nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + spaceX
            lineHeight = 0

        if not testOnly:
            ###########################
            item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), itemSize))

        x = nextX
        ###########################
        lineHeight = max(lineHeight, itemSize.height())

    return y + lineHeight - rect.y() + bottom
```

To make this work as expect you may have to redefine `sizeHint()` of your labels to return a fixed size (instead of the current size).

```
def sizeHint(self):
    return QtCore.QSize(preferredWidth, preferredHeight)
```

[image: Working Layout in action]